# Implementing Button in side menu

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

can someone Help me with fixing this. I want this code to work such as when I click the Home button on the side menu, it should take me to the Main View("This is the Main View"). I have tried using presenting sheets, however, presenting sheet doesn't look realistic. When the Home button is tapped, everything should disappear and only the Home Screen should come up with the side menu. I have tried writing up this code, however, I couldn't make the home button work. The codes are as below:

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import Combine


struct Home: View {
@State var showMenu = false
    @EnvironmentObject var userSettings: UserSettings
  
    var body: some View {
        
        let drag = DragGesture()
            .onEnded {
                if $0.translation.width < -100 {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.showMenu = false
                    }
                }
            }
        return NavigationView {
            
            GeometryReader {
            geometry in
               
            ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                MainView(showMenu: self.$showMenu)
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                .offset(x: self.showMenu ? geometry.size.width/2 : 0)
                .disabled(self.showMenu ? true : false)
                if self.showMenu {
                    MenuView()
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width/2)
                        .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
                }
    }
            .gesture(drag)
        }
            .navigationBarTitle("Pay Data", displayMode: .inline)
       
            .navigationBarItems(leading: (Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    self.showMenu.toggle()
                }
            }){
                Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3")
                    .imageScale(.large)
                
            }
                                         ))
    }
    }
}
struct MainView: View {
    @Binding var showMenu: Bool
        @EnvironmentObject var userSettings: UserSettings
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is Main View")
        
    }
}

struct Home_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Home()
            .environmentObject(UserSettings())
       
    }
}
```

//This is the Menu View. The  Home Button is located in this view.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import Foundation


struct MenuView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userSettings: UserSettings
    @State var showMenu = false
    @State var Homevariable = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            
            Button(action: {
            
                UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "status")
                
               
            }) {
                (Text(Image(systemName: "rectangle.righthalf.inset.fill.arrow.right")) + (Text("Home")))
            }
              
           
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        .background(Color(red: 32/255, green: 32/255, blue: 32/255))
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
 
}
struct MenuView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MenuView()
            .environmentObject(UserSettings())
       
    }
}
```

//This is the another view. I want the side Menu to appear on this as well, so when I press the Home button it takes me to the Main View("This is the Main View")

```
import SwiftUI

struct Calculation: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}

struct Calculation_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Calculation()
    }
}
```

Comment: how many different views/Screens do you plan? And how do you navigate from screen to screen?

Comment: @ChrisR I am planning few screens. However, at this point, I just want this Home Button on the side menu to take me to the Main View. Similarly later I will insert few more buttons on the side menu which will take me to the destination screen of the button. I also want the side menu button(three horizontal lines to appear on every screen when I click the button). Can you help me with that?

Comment: @ChrisR Hi mate, were you able to find the solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. You are basically rebuilding a navigation logic, so in MainView you have to switch between the screens and put the side menu over it:
(PS: you can do without GeometryReader)

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var showMenu = false
    @State private var selected: SelectedScreen = .home
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                // show selected screen
                switch selected {
                case .home:
                    MainView()
                        .disabled(self.showMenu ? true : false)
                case .screen1:
                    OtherView(screen: 1)

                case .screen2:
                    OtherView(screen: 2)
                }
                
                // put menu over it
                if self.showMenu {
                    MenuView(showMenu: $showMenu, selected: $selected)
                        .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Pay Data", displayMode: .inline)
            
            // .navigationBarItems is deprecated, use .toolbar
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Button {
                        withAnimation {
                            self.showMenu.toggle()
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3")
                            .imageScale(.large)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


enum SelectedScreen {
    case home
    case screen1
    case screen2
}


struct MenuView: View {
    
    @Binding var showMenu: Bool
    @Binding var selected: SelectedScreen
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 24) {
            Button {
                selected = .home
                showMenu = false
            } label: {
                Label("Home", systemImage: "rectangle.righthalf.inset.fill.arrow.right")
            }
            
            Button {
                selected = .screen1
                showMenu = false
           } label: {
                Label("Screen 1", systemImage: "1.circle")
            }
 
            Button {
                selected = .screen2
                showMenu = false
            } label: {
                Label("Screen 2", systemImage: "2.circle")
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color(red: 32/255, green: 32/255, blue: 32/255))
            
            Spacer()
    }
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is Main View")
            .font(.largeTitle)
    }
}

struct OtherView: View {
    let screen: Int
    var body: some View {
        Text("Other View: Screen \(screen)")
            .font(.largeTitle)
    }
}
```